# Wordpress - setting a base href

Tags: wordpress

I'm developing a wordpress theme locally and I'm trying to set a base URL for all my images / JS in my wordpress theme. I've tried the standard `<base href="http://localhost:8888/wp-content/themes/my-theme/" />` which does work for my JS and image file (which aren't in the CSS) but it makes my menu links not work.

I've also tried `<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>` which will make the link to my logo image work, but all my images included in my js don't. I've got a supsersized slideshow running as the background image.

Obviously I can use absolute file paths - http://localhost:8888/wp-content/themes/my-theme/images/slides/image1.jpg - but I'm certain there must be another way that will work.

The js for my slideshow images is as follows

```
jQuery(function($){

            $.supersized({

                //Functionality
                slideshow               :   1,      //Slideshow on/off
                autoplay                :   1,      //Slideshow starts playing automatically
                start_slide             :   1,      //Start slide
                slide_interval          :   10000,  //Length between transitions
                transition              :   1,      //0-None, 1-Fade, 2-Slide Top, 3-Slide Right, 4-Slide Bottom, 5-Slide Left, 6-Carousel Right, 7-Carousel Left
                transition_speed        :   500,    //Speed of transition
                new_window              :   1,      //Image links open in new window/tab
                pause_hover             :   0,      //Pause slideshow on hover
                keyboard_nav            :   1,      //Keyboard navigation on/off
                performance             :   1,      //0-Normal, 1-Hybrid speed/quality, 2-Optimizes image quality, 3-Optimizes transition speed // (Only works for Firefox/IE, not Webkit)

                //Size & Position
                min_width               :   0,      //Min width allowed (in pixels)
                min_height              :   0,      //Min height allowed (in pixels)
                vertical_center         :   1,      //Vertically center background
                horizontal_center       :   1,      //Horizontally center background
                fit_portrait            :   1,      //Portrait images will not exceed browser height
                fit_landscape           :   0,      //Landscape images will not exceed browser width

                //Components
                navigation              :   1,      //Slideshow controls on/off
                thumbnail_navigation    :   1,      //Thumbnail navigation
                slide_counter           :   1,      //Display slide numbers
                slide_captions          :   1,      //Slide caption (Pull from "title" in slides array)
                slides                  :   [           // Slideshow Images
                                                    {image : 'http://localhost:8888/wp-content/themes/my-theme/images/slides/image1.jpg'},
                                                    {image : 'http://localhost:8888/wp-content/themes/my-theme/images/slides/image2.jpg'}
                                            ]

            }); 
        });
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

* UPDATED ***

Ok, thanks to Pekka, I've got halfway there..

The code in my header.php file now reads

```
<script type="text/javascript">
template_directory = "<?php echo bloginfo('template_directory');?>";
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo bloginfo('template_directory');?>/js/main-site.js"></script>
```

and in my main-site.js file I've got

```
{image : 'template_directory' + '/images/slides/image1.jpg'}
```

but it just won't display the background images. I've tried with/without the trailing slash - assuming the syntax is incorrect?

Any advice? :)

UPDATED - AGAIN ***

Noticed the '' around template_directory.Now the images are showing BUT the links in my menu aren't working anymore :S

Comment: if you are adde this js inside your php file <?php bloginfo('template_directory');?> is enugh

Comment: Even if it is an external file you can make it a php file and call the php file through script tag.

Comment: @Vasanthan that's a waste of resources though, as the whole (mostly static) JavaScript file is going to run through the PHP interpreter, you have to set up caching individually, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My favourite method of populating paths into JavaScript is to set it in the HTML page's head like so:

```
<!-- Do this in the head, before you include any other Javascript -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  template_directory = "<?php echo bloginfo('template_directory');?>";
</script>
```

and then using the `template_directory` variable in your JavaScript code.

That way, you can still have static JavaScript resources, and you don't need to mess with PHP inside them.

Comment: Ok, I THINK i understand - my javascript skills aren't brilliant. So to instead of referencing the images like this -{image : 'http://localhost:8888/wp-content/themes/my-theme/images/slides/image1.jpg'}, i'd use template_directory +'images/slides/image1.jpg'?

Comment: @VNeal You may or may not need a slash after template_directory, I can't remember whether one is always provided, but otherwise, exactly, yeah!

Comment: Hi - hmm, doesn't seem to want to play. I've updated the post above - I think it's probably something to do with the way I've written it...

Comment: It's ok - I noticed the extra '' around template_directory *doh* - thanks! So, assuming this won't need to change when uploaded to live URL?

Comment: Ok - that's great - HOWEVER now, the links in my menu aren't working. When i take that code out it works. Any ideas?

Comment: @VNeal you probably have a Javascript error somewhere. Look in the JS console

Comment: Yea I've checked that and nothing is showing up in Firebug. I've removed the CSS just in case it was something awry there but the links still don't work :S

Comment: @VNeal what does "not work" mean exactly? What happens? Where are the links pointing to? Is it a Javascript menu?

Comment: Sorry. I'm clicking on the links in the main menu (Home, About etc) and although the URLs are being rendered correctly and I can navigate directly to that URL when typing in the address bar (eg. http://localhost:8888/about/) - when I click on them the browser doesn't navigate to them. I'm stuck on the home page. When i remove the script I've just added it works again :S

Comment: @VNeal do you have a live example somewhere?

Comment: I think i've pinpointed it down to Supersized background image - thanks for all your help though!

Answer (score 0):

I would try putting the jQuery code in the footer, and then when you reference the images, simply use the get_stylesheet_directory_uri() reference. So you'd want something like this:

```
jQuery(function($){

        $.supersized({

            //Functionality
            slideshow               :   1,      //Slideshow on/off
            autoplay                :   1,      //Slideshow starts playing automatically
            start_slide             :   1,      //Start slide
            slide_interval          :   10000,  //Length between transitions
            transition              :   1,      //0-None, 1-Fade, 2-Slide Top, 3-Slide Right, 4-Slide Bottom, 5-Slide Left, 6-Carousel Right, 7-Carousel Left
            transition_speed        :   500,    //Speed of transition
            new_window              :   1,      //Image links open in new window/tab
            pause_hover             :   0,      //Pause slideshow on hover
            keyboard_nav            :   1,      //Keyboard navigation on/off
            performance             :   1,      //0-Normal, 1-Hybrid speed/quality, 2-Optimizes image quality, 3-Optimizes transition speed // (Only works for Firefox/IE, not Webkit)

            //Size & Position
            min_width               :   0,      //Min width allowed (in pixels)
            min_height              :   0,      //Min height allowed (in pixels)
            vertical_center         :   1,      //Vertically center background
            horizontal_center       :   1,      //Horizontally center background
            fit_portrait            :   1,      //Portrait images will not exceed browser height
            fit_landscape           :   0,      //Landscape images will not exceed browser width

            //Components
            navigation              :   1,      //Slideshow controls on/off
            thumbnail_navigation    :   1,      //Thumbnail navigation
            slide_counter           :   1,      //Display slide numbers
            slide_captions          :   1,      //Slide caption (Pull from "title" in slides array)
            slides                  :   [           // Slideshow Images
                                                {image : '<?php echo (get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/images/image1.jpg') ?>'},
                                                {image : '<?php echo (get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/images/image2.jpg') ?>'}
                                        ]

        }); 
    });
```